# Event handler for conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect whether a condition is being returned true or false. The only problem is, I have a bunch of `if`/`else` statements. Is it possible to refactor this in less lines? Maybe a `for` loop or re-writing my markup?

```
$(document).on('click', '.cert-modal-btn', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

        var $this  = $(this); 
    certNcv        = $this.data("ncv"),
    certDealer     = $this.data("cert"),
    certExpress    = $this.data("express"),
    certOne        = $this.data("dealone"),
    certPromise    = $this.data("iscustomer"),
    certEcomm      = $this.data("isecomm"),
    $tabbedMenu    = $('.tabbed-menu').find('li'),
    $certsDescription = $('.certs-description').find('li');

if(certNcv) {
    console.log("certNcv is true");
    $tabbedMenu.eq(0).removeClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(0).removeClass('hidden-item');
}
else {
    $tabbedMenu.eq(0).addClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(0).addClass('hidden-item');
}
if (certExpress == "X") {
    console.log("certExpress is X");
    $tabbedMenu.eq(1).removeClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(1).removeClass('hidden-item');
}
else {
    $tabbedMenu.eq(1).addClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(1).addClass('hidden-item');
}
if(certEcomm) {
    console.log("certEcomm is true");
    $tabbedMenu.eq(2).removeClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(2).removeClass('hidden-item');
}
else {
    $tabbedMenu.eq(2).addClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(2).addClass('hidden-item');
}
if(certOne) {
    console.log("certOne is true");
    $tabbedMenu.eq(3).removeClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(3).removeClass('hidden-item');
}
else {
    $tabbedMenu.eq(3).addClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(3).addClass('hidden-item');
}
if(certPromise) {
    console.log("certPromise is true");
    $tabbedMenu.eq(4).removeClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(4).removeClass('hidden-item');
}
else {
    $tabbedMenu.eq(4).addClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(4).addClass('hidden-item');
}
if(certDealer) {
    console.log("certDealer is true");
    $tabbedMenu.eq(5).removeClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(5).removeClass('hidden-item');
}
else {
    $tabbedMenu.eq(5).addClass('hidden-item');
    $certsDescription.eq(5).addClass('hidden-item');
}
// console.log(certNcv);
// console.log(certDealer); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you start with an array:

```
let certs = ["ncv", "cert", "express", "dealone", "iscustomer", "isecomm"];
```

then it reduces down to a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
    if ($this.data(certs[i])) {
        console.log(certs[i] + " is true");
        $tabbedMenu.eq(i).removeClass('hidden-item');
        $certsDescription.eq(i).removeClass('hidden-item');
    }
    else {
        $tabbedMenu.eq(i).addClass('hidden-item');
        $certsDescription.eq(i).addClass('hidden-item');
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your test `if (certs[i])`doesn't make sense. It needs to be `if ($this.data(certs[i]))`.

Comment: Nice solution, but let me add that this does not take into account the special handling of `(certExpress == "X")`